# How do I pre-populate the createDateBox() or date picker field with the current date?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Ui on a Google Sites page with a date field (date picker). Is there a way to pre-populate it with the current date? Secondly, is there a way of isolating the year from the date picked? Here is the code I have so far:

```
    //Create elements for vPanel_01
    var labelDate = app.createLabel("Date of event:");
    var textBoxDate = app.createDateBox().setName("date").setStyleAttribute("color", "#a7a7a7");
```

I'd like to isolate the year from the input so that I can use for comparisons in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your comment : if I keep megabytes1024's example you should add an handler to the textBox (or to a button hat validates the input) and a callBackElement to this handler and then, in the handler function you can use something like this :

```
var dateObject = new Date(e.parameter.date); // 'date' is the name of the datepicker
```

When you have this date object you can get whatever you want from it, for example :

```
var fullyear = dateObject.getFullYear(); // will return full year in 4 digits
```

[see doc on date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

You could be interested [in this example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dE1rMnFLUUE0cmtGSmx2UVZ4djgzS2c) as well.

Comment: Thanks Serge - appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to pre-populate it with the current date?

The following code does the required.

```
var now = new Date();
var labelDate = app.createLabel("Date of event:");
var textBoxDate = app.createDateBox().setName("date").setStyleAttribute("color", "#a7a7a7").setValue(now);
```

> is there a way of isolating the year from the date picked?

Please explain what do you expect to have by writing `isolating the year from the date picked`? Do you need to extract a year of a date? If yes, the the following does it.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var now = new Date();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Current Year: ' + now.getFullYear()));
  return app;
}
```

The code which extracts year from a date box.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var now = new Date();
  var dateBox = app.createDateBox().setName('datebox').setValue(now);
  var label = app.createLabel(now).setId('label');
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('onBtnClick');
  handler.addCallbackElement(dateBox);
  var btn = app.createButton('Click Me').addClickHandler(handler);
  app.add(dateBox);
  app.add(label);
  app.add(btn);
  return app;
}

function onBtnClick(e) {
  var selectedDate = new Date(e.parameter.datebox);
  var year = selectedDate.getFullYear();
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var label = app.getElementById('label');
  label.setText('Selected Date: ' + selectedDate + ', Year: ' + year);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.  As far as the year is concerned - this is what I'm trying to do: I have a spreadsheet in my google docs that has a sheet in it named "2012" (for the current year). The script pushes data to this spreadsheet. When I select a date and fill out other text fields I need the script to check and see if the year has changed and if so duplicate the 2012 sheet and rename it to the new year.

Comment: So I would need the year of the date that was picked not the current date that was pre-populated...